# Quiero hacer un boton copie el countdown

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extensión-google-chrome

!uisiera hacer un botton de **countdouwn** para una extensión de manera localhost que pero lamentablemente no se que estaré haciendo mal, cabe destacar que la **web donde quiero usarla ya existe** quiero solo tomar el tiempo de countdown para regresar al sitio cuando halla terminado dicho conteo, **quiero que sea completamente localhost** ya que lo requiero para mi archivo.bat, que hace que regrese "**forzado**" en sentido que como se me olvida ella me llevaría o por lo menos esa es la idea, que me force a ir cuando este en la pc solo cuando es necesario  para que sea ejecutado ya en segundo plano cuando halla terminado y el conteo me hará regresar.
El punto .bat quiero ejecutarlo de manera **localhost** me hace falta incluir setTimeout() ni setInterval() pero no se como introducirlo a mi código

```js
function marcado() {//CREA EL BOTON Copy Countdown   INICIO

         if (typeof marca !== "number") {

          if (document.getElementsByClassName("countdown_show2").length) {
         
           if (document.getElementById("d2fbcptime")+(1) === 1) {

            var d2fbcptime = document.createElement("button");
            document.body.appendChild(d2fbcptime);
            d2fbcptime.setAttribute("id", "d2fbcptime");
            d2fbcptime.setAttribute("style", "display:block; margin:auto;")
            document.getElementById("d2fbcptime").textContent="Copy Countdown";

            var chamon = document.createElement("br");
            document.body.appendChild(chamon);
            chamon.setAttribute("id", "chamon");

            evd2fbcptime()

            marca = 0;
           }

          }
         }
        }

        function evd2fbcptime() {/*CREA UN EVENTO DE ESCUCHA, PARA CUANDO SE HAGA CLICK EN EL BOTON Copy Countdown*/
         if (document.getElementById("d2fbcptime")+(1) !== 1){
         document.getElementById("d2fbcptime").addEventListener("click", copyToClipboard);
         clearInterval(evd2fbcptime);
         }
        }
        function copyToClipboard(){/*CREAR CUADRO DE DIALOGO PARA PONER LO COPIADO INICIO*/

          if (document.getElementById("chamon")+(1) !== 1) {
           var elementta = document.getElementById("chamon");
           elementta.parentNode.removeChild(elementta);
          } 
             
          if (document.getElementById("dummy_id")+(1) !== 1) {
           var element = document.getElementById("dummy_id");
           element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
          }

          if (document.getElementById("chaman")+(1) !== 1) {
           var elementt = document.getElementById("chaman");
           elementt.parentNode.removeChild(elementt);
          }

          if (document.getElementsByClassName("countdown_show2").length) {
          var yola = document.getElementsByClassName("countdown_show2")[0].textContent;
          
          var dummy = document.createElement("input");
          document.body.appendChild(dummy);
          dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");
          dummy.setAttribute("style", "display:block; margin:auto; text-align:center;")
          document.getElementById("dummy_id").value=yola;
          dummy.select();
          document.execCommand("copy");

          var chaman = document.createElement("br");
          document.body.appendChild(chaman);
          chaman.setAttribute("id", "chaman");

          } else {

         if (document.getElementById("d2fbcptime")+(1) !== 1) {
          var compbtntmctn = document.getElementById("d2fbcptime");
          document.body.removeChild(compbtntmctn);
         }
              
          }
                            };
         /*INTERVALO INICIADOR DEL CREADOR DEL BOTON COPY COUNTDOWN
         LLAMA AL CREADOR DEL BOTON COPY COUNTDOWN   Aquí debería ir mi 
         setTimeout() y mi setInterval() falta añadirlo porque no cuento 
          con este codigo no se como añadirlo sin necesidad de hacer un 
            sessionStorage*/
```

```html
<div id="time_remaining" class="hasCountdown"><span class="countdown_row countdown_show2"><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">24</span><br>Minutes</span><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">20</span><br>Seconds</span></span></div>
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien el planteamiento, mencionas un archivo `.bat`, pero  no cómo planeas ejecutarlo. También mencionas un intervalo, pero no hay `setTimeout()` ni `setInterval()` en tu código. Finalmente, ¿qué uso planeas darle al texto copiado?. Por favor edita la pregunta para redactar nuevamente qué es lo que quieres hacer, qué es lo que no has logrado y, si recibes un mensaje de error, incluirlo completo y mencionar en qué línea ocurre.

Comment: El poder de las comas no te acompaña, intenta formular la pregunta algo mejor para que sea entendible (los signos de puntuación son muy útiles para dar sentido a un texto).

Comment: @Triby Hice aclaraciones mas exacta a mi parecer correspondiente a lo que tengo en mi código

Comment: @AQMR la pregunta que trato de plantear como hago para que esto me sirva de manera localhost sin necesidad de que lo lleve fuera de una web y poder añadirle un setInterval() sin sessionStorage